# Variable types in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, scope

I'm not quite sure the uses for the different variables in CoffeeScript

```
class Cow
  @utters = 1

  constructor: (@name) ->

  mutate:->
     alert @utters

  heads: 1
  feet = 9


c = new Cow
```

From my investigation, it seems `heads` is public and `feet` is private.  My confusion comes in when figuring out `name` and `utters`.  For `name` it more or less compiles to `this.name = name` and for `utters` it compiles to `Cow.utters = 1`.

So my questions are.  What is the scope of `utters` and how should it be accessed?  What is the scope of `name` and how should it be accessed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us look at these one by one.

For the [first one](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Cow%0A%20%20@utters%20=%201):

```
class Cow
  @utters = 1
```

`this` is the class itself when you hit `@utters = 1` so this `@utters` is sort of a class variable. The JavaScript version is this:

```
var Cow = (function() {
  function Cow() {}
  Cow.utters = 1;
  return Cow;
})();
```

Subclasses will be able to see this but they'll have their own copy of it; so, for this:

```
class CowCow extends Cow
  m: ->
    CowCow.utters = 11
```

`CowCow.utters` starts out as 1 but will be 11 after `(new CowCow).m()` and `Cow.utters` will stay at 1 all the way through.

The [second one](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Cow%0A%20%20heads%3a%201):

```
class Cow
  heads: 1
```

is essentially a default instance variable; the JavaScript version looks like this:

```
var Cow = (function() {
  function Cow() {}
  Cow.prototype.heads = 1;
  return Cow;
})();
```

The `Cow.prototype.heads = 1;` part means that `heads` is inherited and attached to instances rather than classes.

The result is that this:

```
class Cow
  heads: 1

class CowCow extends Cow
  m: ->
    alert @heads
    @heads = 11

(new CowCow).m()
alert (new Cow).heads
```

alerts 1 twice.

The [third one](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Cow%0A%20%20feet%20=%209%0A%20%20m%3a%20-%3E%20alert%20feet):

```
class Cow
  feet = 9
  m: -> alert feet
```

is another sort of class variable but this one is very private: `feet` is not inherited, not visible to subclasses, and not visible to the outside world. The JavaScript version is this:

```
var Cow = (function() {
  var feet = 9;
  function Cow() {}
  Cow.prototype.m = function() { return alert(feet) };
  return Cow;
})();
```

so you can see that:

1. `feet` will be visible to all `Cow` methods.
2. All `Cow` instances will share the same `feet`.
3. `feet` is not public in that you can't get at it without calling a `Cow` method (class or instance, either will do).
4. `feet` is not visible to subclasses since it isn't a property of the class and it isn't in the `prototype` (and thus it isn't inherited by instances of subclasses).

---

**Summary**: `@utters` is sort of a traditional class variable, `heads` is a public instance variable with a default value, and `feet` is sort of a private class variable.