# Coffeescript classes and variables

Tags: class, coffeescript

Say I have a Coffeescript class like this:

```
class Foo
    aVar = 'foo'

    someFunction = ->
        anotherVar = 'bar'
```

Is there a way to set `anotherVar` as a class variable without having to declare it as null, like so:

```
class Foo
    aVar = 'foo'
    anotherVar = null

    someFunction = ->
        anotherVar = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Let us look at a simple class:

```
class C
    cv = null
    m: -> cv
```

That is converted to this JavaScript:

```
var C = (function() {
  var cv;
  function C() {}
  cv = null;
  C.prototype.m = function() {
    return cv;
  };
  return C;
})();
```

You'll notice that the "private class variable" `cv` is just a local variable inside the self-executing function that builds `C`. So, if we wanted to add a new "private class variable" to `C`, we'd have to open that anonymous function's scope again and add new variables. But there's no way to travel back in time and alter the scope of a function that has already executed so you're out of luck.

You don't have to define your `anotherVar` as `null` when you define it but you have to initialize it to something.

Comment: Lame, I thought there may be a way, like you can do with static vars by prepending `@`; oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about `this` keyword? :) CoffeeScript maps `@` into `this`:

```
class Foo
    aVar = 'foo'

    someFunction: ->
        @anotherVar = 'bar'
```

Comment: But that makes it a 'public' (static) variable, I want it to be 'private', e.g. for it to only exist and be accessible within the class.

Comment: There is no such thing as *private* variables in JavaScript. That's one thing. And the second: `someFunction` is mapped to a property of `prototype` of `Foo`. The code you've wrote above won't even work. Prototype functions can only access variables within `this` context. If you want to use *private* variables, then you have to define `someFunction` within a constructor of `Foo` with `@` prefix.

Comment: Woops! I've updated my question to reflect the rewriting of `someFunction`.

Comment: But you can simulate *private* in certain contexts by taking advantage of the function wrappers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347993/479863

Comment: @muistooshort Oh, yeah. I forgot that CoffeeScript wraps everything again in an anonymous function. Thank you for remainding me!