# How to parse/understand this coffeescript syntax?

Tags: coffeescript

I have come across this construct a few times.

Example 1:

```
_  = require 'underscore'

class Controller extends App

  _doSomething: _.throttle (event) ->
    $div = $(event.target).closest 'div'
    ...
```

**My Question:**

I have trouble understanding why this construct is valid.

Normally a class function definition goes like:

```
  _doSomething: (event) ->
    $div = $(event.target).closest 'div'
    ...
    , 500
```

So how can `_.throttle` sit in between `:` and `(event)` the function parameter?

If `_.throttle` is supposed to act as an wrapper, shouldn't it be written as

```
  _doSomething = _.throttle( (event) ->   # an anonymous function that takes event as parameter
    $div = $(event.target).closest 'div'
    ...
    , 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things might be clearer if we add the optional parentheses:

```
class Controller extends App
  _doSomething: _.throttle( (event) ->
    $div = $(event.target).closest 'div'
    ...
  )
```

Now we see that `_.throttle` is function call and it is being given an anonymous function as its single argument. We can break it down a bit more to further clarify what's going on:

```
f = (event) ->
  $div = $(event.target).closest('div')
  ...
throttled_function = _.throttle(f)

class Controller extends App
  _doSomething: throttled_function
```

[`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) returns a function so the code you're looking at just just a complicated version of:

```
class Controller extends App
  _doSomething: some_function
```

which is nothing special. Keep in mind that you can use anonymous functions when building a class's methods but named functions or other expressions which evaluate to functions serve just as well; the syntax is really:

```
name: expr
```

where `expr` is some expression and `f(x)` (or `_.throttle(some_anonymous_function)`) is an expression.

Comment: Sometimes I am not sure if this optionality in the syntax is worth it or not. Thanks for a great explanation

Comment: I include the parentheses almost all the time. I'm tired of memorizing precedence tables and trying to mentally parse code, the extra parentheses make things a lot clearer to me. I do the same in Ruby and I don't care if it isn't politically correct.

Comment: I think I struggle a bit because conceptually I ain't sure when to use ':' and when to use '='. Totally agree with the 'politically incorrect' point. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyKong: `class` is basically a function with some extra stuff to set up inheritance and such. So, if you say `f = -> ...` then you're essentially defining a variable that is local to that class; if you say `p: ...` then you're defining a property. I wrote a little more about this [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347993/479863).