# Why does instance method doesn't work?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm studying `coffescript`. I want an instance method (`@generate_human`) to run during every instantination of the class, but I'm getting error that the function doesn't exist. When I change the method to be the class method instead, everything works. What is going on?

```
class Human  # As biological creature
    constructor: (@given_sex = null,
                  @age = null,  # Age of the person
                  @max_age = 85) ->  # Maximum allowed age of the person during person generation


        _alive = true

        alive: ->
            @_alive

        dead: ->
            not @alive()

        has_died: ->
            @_alive = false

        _available_sexes: {0: 'female', 1: 'male'}

        sex: ->
            _sex = @_available_sexes[@given_sex]

        generate_human: ->
            @_alive = true
            if @age is null
                @age = Math.floor(Math.random() * @max_age)
            if @given_sex is null
                @given_sex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
            else if @given_sex not in [0,1]
                n = @given_sex
                err = 'Invalid sex value: ' + n
                console.log(err)
                throw new Error(err)

         @generate_human()  # In JavaScript this line throws an error that function 'this.generate_human()' does not exist

h = new Human()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the class level, `@` (AKA `this`) is the class itself. When you say this:

```
class C
  @m()
```

the `@` in `@m()` will be referring to the class itself, not an instance of the class. If you look at the JavaScript version you should see what's going on:

```
var C = (function() {
  function C() {}
  C.m(); // <---------- This is the @m() call.
  return C;
})();
```

This lines up with the syntax for defining a class method:

```
class C
  @m: ->
```

which becomes this JavaScript:

```
var C = (function() {
  function C() {}
  C.m = function() {}; // <--------- Here is the class method.
  return C;
})();
```

If you want the method to run when an instance is created, call it in `constructor`:

```
class Human
  constructor: (@given_sex = null, @age = null, @max_age = 85) ->
    @generate_human()
  #...
```

You probably want to look at what CoffeeScript does to that `_alive = true` too, that doesn't define a default `@_alive` instance variable, that is actually a [private class variable of sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9347993/479863); you probably want `_alive: true` instead.

Also, you should be very very careful and consistent with your whitespace in CoffeeScript, any variation or inconsistency can cause strange and puzzling errors. For example, I'd recommend against that format for your `constructor` definition and you'll have a better time if all your methods are at the same indentation level.

Comment: I fail to see the difference in my calling `@generate_human()` and yours. They are both called under `constructor` and it is the only reasonable place to call it. To my opinion the issue is where this method defined: if I define it inside constructor as you see in my code than `@generate_human()` throws an exception; if I define it outside `constructor` the call succeeds and I don't understand why it is not working in the way I wrote it initially (I define method in constructor and call it straight away). Could you change my code so it would work with `generate_human:->` inside constructor?

Comment: So you're actually trying to put all that stuff inside `constructor`? I assumed that the indentation was a copy'n'paste error as that structure doesn't make sense, that stuff should be outside `constructor` if you want to to be part of the class. If all that is inside `constructor` then it doesn't do anything, it just like defining an object literal and then ignoring it completely.